# Converting a string into data frame

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have extracted a file and got the file in the following format. The XXXX's are values to be ignored. What I am attempting to do is extract the values out of the data frame. The values I am looking at are after A. Below is what the string from the file looks like. The second diagram is what I am attempting to get the data frame.

Text

```
XXXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXXX

Date

Time

A

2021-01-17
2021-01-18
XXXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXXX


12
14

21
2
```

This is what I am trying to get the data frame to look like.

[image]

I tried to read the data frame separating the lines in and not sure how to proceed further.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\n') # This puts the text into the data frame
df[7:14] # This would return a slice in the database
```

Comment: How would you decide which lines to keep?  It would be better to filter the file so it only has the data you want, and then import that into pandas.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

text = '''
     # <your text value
'''
# cleaning the text
text = [j for j in [i for i in text.split('\n') if i != '' ] if j[0] != 'X']
text.insert(5, 'B')
text.insert(8, 'C')
text.remove('Date')
text.remove('Time')

text = [text[i*3:i*3+3] for i in range(3)]   
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(text).T)
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT :**
[image]